# Discord.py Cog extension is raising a ModuleNotFoundError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm writing a discord bot and recently decided to move all of the commands into "Cogs". All of the python files within my cog folder import other modules I've written that have helper functions and whatnot in them (I store them in a named *cutils*). They seem to import fine, but when I try to run the bot, I am getting the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 607, in _load_from_module_spec
    spec.loader.exec_module(lib)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/pi/Code/bot/cogs/moderation.py", line 6, in <module>
    import cutils.util as util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cutils'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./craig.py", line 43, in <module>
    client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 664, in load_extension
    self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 610, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.moderation' raised an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cutils'
```

All of my modules in the cutils directory raise this error and I cannot figure out why.

Here is the directory tree:

```
bot/
  cogs/
    cutils/ <-- the modules being imported by moderation.py
      __init__.py
      util.py
      md.py
    __init__.py
    moderation.py <-- the cog extension
  bot.py
```

bot.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import os
import logging

from cogs.cutils import util

TOKEN = "token"
LOG_MESSAGE_FORMAT = "%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s"

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")

@client.command()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    client.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
    client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    args = util.get_args()
    print(f"Running bot.py with args {args}")

    logging.basicConfig(
        level=args.logging,
        format=LOG_MESSAGE_FORMAT
    )
    
    for filename in os.listdir("cogs"):
        if filename.endswith(".py"):
            client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
    
    client.run(TOKEN)
```

And here is moderation.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import logging

import cutils.util as util
import cutils.md as md

class Moderation(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def command1(self, ctx):
        do_stuff()
    
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Moderation(client))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to still act as if you were importing from **bot.py**

```py
from cogs.cutils import util
from cogs.cutils import md
```